# vs code 1.47.1 automatically reformatting dart code files

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code

Unfortunately I replied yes
to a vs code prompt for a settings change and now,
when I edit a .dart file, it is automatically reformatted.
In some cases git shows the entire file has been modified.
In some places 2 spaces are replaced with 4 spaces.
In another place code was added.
The time stamp on the settings.json file is today (July 14, 2020) at 11:20AM PST.

Is there a way to find out the latest changes to the settings.json file?

before:

```
  icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.solidBuilding), /*Icon(Icons.format_list_bulleted ),*/
```

after:

```
  icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.solidBuilding),
  /*Icon(Icons.format_list_bulleted ),*/
```

before:

```
  MyClass({
    this.field1,
    this.field2,
    this.field3
  });
```

after:

```
MyClass({this.field1,this.field2,this.field3});
```

before:

```
child: Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
  children: <Widget>[
    AvatarUpload(
```

after:

```
 child: Column(
   crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
   children: <Widget>[
   AvatarUpload(
   AvatarUpload( 
   AvatarUpload(
```

What is the setting that I need to revert?

settings.json

```
{
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/.git": true,
        "**/.svn": true,
        "**/.hg": true,
        "**/CVS": true,
        "**/.DS_Store": true,
        "**/*.js": { "when": "$(basename).ts"}
    },
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-simpler-icons",
    "editor.insertSpaces": true,
    "editor.detectIndentation": false,
    "solidity.linter": "solhint",
      "solidity.solhintRules": {
        "avoid-sha3": "warn"
      },
      "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
      "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
      "java.configuration.checkProjectSettingsExclusions": false,
      "peacock.favoriteColors": [
        {
          "name": "Angular Red",
          "value": "#b52e31"
        },
        {
          "name": "Auth0 Orange",
          "value": "#eb5424"
        },
        {
          "name": "Azure Blue",
          "value": "#007fff"
        },
        {
          "name": "C# Purple",
          "value": "#68217A"
        },
        {
          "name": "Gatsby Purple",
          "value": "#639"
        },
        {
          "name": "Go Cyan",
          "value": "#5dc9e2"
        },
        {
          "name": "Java Blue-Gray",
          "value": "#557c9b"
        },
        {
          "name": "JavaScript Yellow",
          "value": "#f9e64f"
        },
        {
          "name": "Mandalorian Blue",
          "value": "#1857a4"
        },
        {
          "name": "Node Green",
          "value": "#215732"
        },
        {
          "name": "React Blue",
          "value": "#00b3e6"
        },
        {
          "name": "Something Different",
          "value": "#832561"
        },
        {
          "name": "Vue Green",
          "value": "#42b883"
        }
      ],
      "dart.debugExternalLibraries": true,
      "dart.debugSdkLibraries": false,
      "[yaml]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "redhat.vscode-yaml"
      },
      "dart.openDevTools": "flutter",
      "[json]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
      },
      "diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": false,
      "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 10,
      "[dart]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": true,
        "editor.formatOnType": true,
        "editor.rulers": [
          80
        ],
        "editor.selectionHighlight": false,
        "editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false,
        "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
        "editor.tabCompletion": "onlySnippets",
        "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one:

```
"[dart]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.formatOnType": true,
    ...
}
```

Change it to `"editor.formatOnSave": false,` and `"editor.formatOnType": false,` depends on your taste.

Comment: Also, you can save without formatting on a circumstantial basis using CRTL + k + SHIFT + s; just FYI for future question seekers.